# Is $\frac{1-z}{|1-z|}$ is holomorphic in $|z|<1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z) = \frac{1-z}{|1-z|}$ with $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|< 1$. I want to know whether $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $|z|<1.$

Write $\frac{1-z}{|1-z|}=e^{i\arg(1-z)}$, where $\arg$ denotes the principal argument (from $-\pi$ to $\pi$). Then $$f(z)=e^{i\arg(1-z)}.$$
I know $e^w$ is an entire function of $w$. So it suffices to see if $\arg(1-z)$ is holomorphic in $|z|<1.$ Is this true?

Comment: Hint: This is a function from an open set to the unit circle.

Comment: You are asking if a real-valued function is holomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

The argument function has real values. If you think of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, it follows that it must be constant if it is holomorphic.

Your function is also not holomorphic. Assume for a contradiction that it is. By the maximum modulus principle, since $|f(z)|$ is constant, $f(z)$ has to be constant. But your $f(z)$ is not constant.